# Not able to Scroll React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I was creating an app that sells ebooks and when creating the details page for each book, I wrapped the entire component with a scroll view but it does not work, you can see my result in the screen recording attached, I looked through many solutions but could not find a fix for my issue,

Here is my code of the component that's causing the issue:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from '../../axios.config';
import {ScrollView, View, Text, Image, useWindowDimensions} from 'react-native';
import RenderHtml from 'react-native-render-html';

import Button from '../../components/Button';
import OutlineButton from '../../components/OutlineButton';
import Rating from '../../components/Rating';
import Header from './components/Header';
import BookDataRail from './components/BookDataRail';

import {Book} from '../../types/Book';
import {ReadBook, PlayWhite} from '../../icons';
import styles from './styles';
import Review from '../../components/Review';

interface BookDetailsProps {}

const BookDetails: React.FC<BookDetailsProps> = () => {
  const [bookDetails, setBookDetails] = useState<Book>();
  const {width} = useWindowDimensions();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const {data} = await axios.post('/', {
        method: 'bookdetails',
        book_id: 4,
      });

      setBookDetails(data);
    };

    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <ScrollView scrollEnabled={true} contentContainerStyle={{backgroundColor: "white", flexGrow: 1}}>
        {/* Cover Image/Header */}
        <View
          style={{
            height: '40%',
          }}>
          <Header coverUrl={bookDetails?.cover_url} />
        </View>
        {/* Content */}
        <View style={styles.body}>
          {/* Book Title */}
          <Text style={styles.bookTitleText}>{bookDetails?.title}</Text>
          {/* Author Name */}
          <Text style={styles.authorNameText}>{bookDetails?.author_name}</Text>
          {/* Main Rating */}
          <View style={styles.ratingContainer}>
            <Rating
              rating={bookDetails ? bookDetails.rating_review.rating : 0}
            />
          </View>
          {/* Play Audio/Read Book Buttons */}
          <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
            <Button
              title="Play Audio"
              width={'48%'}
              leftAccessory={
                <Image source={PlayWhite} style={styles.buttonIcon} />
              }
            />
            <OutlineButton
              title="Read Book"
              width={'48%'}
              leftAccessory={
                <Image source={ReadBook} style={styles.buttonIcon} />
              }
            />
          </View>
          {/* Add to Wishlist */}
          <Text style={styles.addToWishlistText}>+ Add to Wishlist</Text>
          {/* Book Details Rail */}
          <View style={styles.bookRailContainer}>
            {bookDetails && (
              <BookDataRail
                downloads={bookDetails.downloads}
                language={bookDetails.language}
                pages={bookDetails.num_pages}
                genre={bookDetails.genre_name}
              />
            )}
          </View>
          {/* Book Description */}
          <View style={styles.descriptionContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Summary</Text>
            <ScrollView
              nestedScrollEnabled
              style={styles.descriptionTextContainer}>
              <RenderHtml
                contentWidth={width}
                source={{html: bookDetails?.description || ''}}
              />
            </ScrollView>
          </View>
          {/* Ratings */}
          <View style={styles.ratingsContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Reviews</Text>
            {/* Ratings Header */}
            <View style={styles.ratingsHeader}>
              <Text style={styles.ratingText}>
                {bookDetails?.rating.toFixed(1)}
              </Text>
              <View>
                <View style={styles.ratingContainerSmall}>
                  <Rating
                    rating={bookDetails ? bookDetails.rating_review.rating : 0}
                    noText
                  />
                </View>
                <Text style={styles.numRatingsText}>
                  {bookDetails?.rating_review.review_comments.length || 0}{' '}
                  reviews
                </Text>
              </View>
            </View>
            {/* Showing all reviews */}
            <View style={styles.reviewCommentsContainer}>
              {bookDetails?.rating_review.review_comments.map(
                (reviewComment, index) => (
                  <Review
                    key={index}
                    name={reviewComment.name}
                    rating={reviewComment.rating}
                    date={reviewComment.date}
                    comment={reviewComment.comment}
                  />
                ),
              )}
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

export default BookDetails;
```

The issue is definitely with the top view that's containing the header, if I remove it it works file, I also tried using it without the `Header` component inside, but it still does not work...

And here is the result I'm getting
https://drive.google.com/file/d/121x2CNuj3M63aJu_Z1PjxYbYxivCrhuP/view?usp=sharing

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: If you set a fixed height on the ScrollView, does it scroll? For example, height: 200.
I guess it just expands based on its content so it doesn't need to scroll; probably a flex 1 is enough to fix the issue, but all depends on the overall structure.

Comment: It scrolls if I specify a height for eg. "150%" but I tried adding `flex: 1` to both style and contentContainerStyle but none of them work, adding a fixed height doesn't work for me as there is a lot of dynamic content in this page

Comment: Could you please upload your styles code. Maybe that would help.

Comment: As I said it all depends on the overall structure, so it's hard to tell what you are missing without seeing an entire example. `flex:1` or simply `flexGrow:1` could be needed on parent too, and maybe you have to go up the tree too, or you need something else depending on the applied style. The end result you should strive to get is to make that ScrollView expand to take the available space on the screen but no more.

Comment: I updated the question with my entire component tree

Comment: can you show the code with Scroll view. the main issue is with Scroll view but you did not share it?

Comment: I debugged the code a lot and updated the question with my latest findings, could you please look into it and tell me what's wrong

Answer (score 1):

How about wrapping the scrollview comp inside a container like below

```
<View style = {{ flex : 1 }}>
  <ScrollView contentContainerStyle = {{ flexGrow : 1 }}>
  </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Comment: This did not work for me, if it's any help when I added a background color to the scroll view inside the `contentContainerStyle` prop, it only affected content till the screen size, the content that would have been shown when scrolling did not get affected by the `backgroundColor`

Comment: @HostilePixie Could you edit the question to add the styles file

Comment: Yep, added it as the last file

Comment: @HostilePixie It's still a little difficult to say what's wrong really. The style names don't match the components completely. Just a question, have you checked if the scroll works without the <Header />?

Comment: omg yes it works without the header, could it be because I'm using `position: "absolute"` in the header for some places anyway, I've added the header code to my question, could you please tell me what's wrong in it.....

Comment: @HostilePixie Sorry it's still hard to pin down, looks like there are more child components, eg < HeaderLinearGradient />. I'd suggest finding out the exact cause by removing items and adding them one by one until the scroll stops working. I don't think the absolute positioning is the problem.

Comment: The problem is in the `HeaderLinearGradient` component I added the code to my question, if possible could you look through it and see what's wrong, thanks

Comment: @HostilePixie I think I've reached a dead end. I was trying an example of LinearGradient inside a ScrollView and it worked fine. At this point I'd try replacing the linear gradient with a normal View (keep the styles and children as it is) and confirm that it works. If it does then you'd have to check if LinearGradient could interfere with scroll.

Comment: I tried replacing the `LinearGradient` with a `View` but it still does not work, I also tried setting the height of the component to something like `1%` which then makes it so that I can almost scroll to the bottom, so I think the issue is with the component  not the `LinearGradient`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to apply `contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}` and `container={{flex: 1}}`?

Seems like it should do the trick

Comment: I just tried, still getting the same issue 